# UICollectionViewController reorder without long press

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, ios9

Using a UICollectionViewController I can easily enable reorder. But to actually reorder I have to long press the cell for the reorder state to begin. (Notice the delay from the circle appears to the cell actually moves.)
[image: long press begins dragging]

Since I'm using edit-mode in a springboard-like way, I need the reorder state to begin immediately when touch and holding, not after the long press threshold.

Any idea how to accomplish this? - or at least how to approach it?

Would it be possible to manually fire the long press event on cell touch? If yes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone should come around, here's how I solved it.

It's actually relatively easy to skip the long press and implement a UIPanGestureRecognizer instead. Just implement Begin and Ended changes, and move the index of the current item.
The problem arises when you want to move above or below the fold. Then the Pan Gesture Recognizer' move starts to conflict with the uicollectionview scroll.

I solved it by adding a dragging handle to each cell, and adding a UIPanGestureRecognizer to each dragging handle, calling back to the same method in the VC.

This enables you to scroll by swiping on the items. And if you drag on the handles on each cell, you start to reorder.

I'm still considering wheather this is the most obvious usability, but it works.